# Maximum Green function

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

good morning

does anyone know how to prove that
$|G(x,t)| \le \frac{1}{2}$,

where

$G(x,t)=\begin{cases}
\frac{(x-1)(t+1)}{2} \quad -1 \le t \le x \le 1\\
\frac{(x+1)(t-1)}{2} \quad -1 \le x \le t \le 1\\
\end{cases}
$

Is it possible to do it, using the Hessian method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly $G(x,t)$ is symmetric in $x,t$ and $G(0,0)=-\frac{1}{2}$so $%
|G(0,0)|=\frac{1}{2}$. In view of the symmetry in $x,t$ we can restrict
our attention to the case $x>t$. Then
$$
G(x,t)=\frac{(x-1)(t+1)}{2}\Rightarrow \;|G(x,t)|=\frac{(1-x)(1+t)}{2}%
=F(x,t).
$$
We have
$$
F(1,t)=0,\;F(x,-1)=0,\;F(0,0)=\frac{1}{2}
$$
and around $(0,0)$ we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
t &=&-\varepsilon <0<x=+\delta \;\Rightarrow \;F(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\delta
)(1-\varepsilon )<\frac{1}{2} \\
x &=&+\delta >t=+\varepsilon >0\;\Rightarrow \;F(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\delta
)(1+\varepsilon )<\frac{1}{2} \\
t &=&-\varepsilon <x=-\delta <0\;\Rightarrow \;F(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}(1+\delta
)(1-\varepsilon )<\frac{1}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus it seems that the maximum $1/2$ is obtained in $(0,0)$. I leave the
rest to you.